# Best practice for time dependent variables

Tags: java, time, duration

I have a system that operates with real-time events.  The user can interject custom events at a specified interval.  The real-time engine uses java.time.Duration to time the events.  The user is presented a menu via jsp that has a specification of the Duration in (whole) seconds.  The event list is serialized as Long values.  So I have three ways of using the same value.  I have created a value object that performs the conversions on each access so I don't have to scatter the conversions throughout the code.  I'm wondering whether there is a better way to accomplish this scenario.  Here is my VO.

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class PeriodicCommandVO {
    private String id;
    private String command;
    private Duration duration;
    private Long interval;
    private Long frequency;
    private boolean active;
    public String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }
    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
    public Long getInterval() {
        if (interval == null) {
            if (duration != null) interval = duration.toMillis();
            else {
                if (frequency != null) interval = frequency*1000;
            }
        }
        return interval;
    }
    public void setInterval(Long interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
        this.duration = Duration.ofMillis(interval);
        this.frequency = (interval+500)/1000;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        if (duration == null) {
            if (interval != null) duration = Duration.ofMillis(interval);
            else {
                if (frequency != null) duration = Duration.ofMillis(frequency*1000);
            }
        }
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
        this.interval = duration.toMillis();
        this.frequency = (interval+500)/1000;
    }
    public Long getFrequency() {
        if (frequency == null) {
            if (duration != null) frequency = (duration.toMillis()+500)/1000;
            else {
                if (interval != null) frequency = (interval+500)/1000;
            }
        }
        return frequency;
    }
    public void setFrequency(Long frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.interval = frequency*1000;
        this.duration = Duration.ofSeconds(frequency);
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: To me, it looks like `duration`, `interval` and `frequency` are all representing the same thing. If they aren't, then could you explain the details?

Comment: Yes they are all representing the same thing.

Comment: Then you should drop two of them. Storing a `Duration` is fine, as this can easily be converted to a fixed time unit.

Comment: And by the way, [*value objects* should be immutable](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html).

Comment: I don't have the code of when I dropped frequency.  I removed the declaration of frequency but left the getter and setter intact.  The jsp was unable to  find the variable without the declaration.  Is there some way to overcome the blindness of the jsp?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the frequency while you already have the interval?

Comment: I agree that VO should be immutable.  I also now see that I should be taking care of this in the form, not in the VO.  Thanks for your comments MC Emperor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the seconds-to-duration conversion logic to the constructor for the VO, so the VO can remain immutable.  The jsp now can use the seconds value without conversion, and the controller will receive the value in seconds via the POST in the form.  Reduced the variables in the VO to only store Duration (it's the most general implementation).  My VO now looks like this

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class PeriodicCommandVO {
    private String id;
    private String command;
    private Duration duration;
    private boolean active;

    public PeriodicCommandVO (PeriodicCommandForm form) {
        this.id = form.getId();
        this.command = form.getCommand();
        this.duration = Duration.ofSeconds(form.getFrequency());
    }
    public String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }
    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Additionally, I changed the serialization logic to store the Duration object using ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(), rather than the milliseconds using ObjectOutputStream.writeLong().  The result is that the only conversion between the different representations is in the VO constructor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).